# How to asynchronously work on a data buffer in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-multithreading

I have the following use case:

I am filling a list LIST_A with some data. Every time the list is not empty I want to perform another action on the data and remove it from that list. LIST_A is sort of like a buffer.

Is it possible to do this in a single python script or should I go with a simple database and two separate scripts where the second one continuously checks if there is something to do?

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Yes. I wrote a simple synchronous script that blocks the list filling when it processes the data. So simply data input => process data => data input => process data ...
But I wonder how something like this would work on a backend. I read about message brokers and caches like redis. But I'm a total beginner on this subject so I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the python multiprocessing "process" class, more info here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html. This allows you to spawn another process that uses the code of a target function in your script. It should be very doable in a single script this way.

You also might need to implement mutexes so that there are no race conditions when editing the list.

Comment: You're right mb heres python 3! https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html